# Module not found: Can't resolve 'components/Campgrounds' in 'C:\Users\krish\Downloads\krishtest\reactapp\src'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Not sure why but I'm getting an error. I started it with create-react-app.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Campgrounds from 'components/Campgrounds';
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Campgrounds />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Camgrounds.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class Campgrounds extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hi</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Campgrounds
```

[Code Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4KXI.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `import Campgrounds from 'components/Campgrounds';` with `import Campgrounds from './components/Campgrounds';` and your app should work fine.